# Clear Array, before re-creating array to stop duplicate drop down options in Angular HTML SELECT when data refresh or reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an issue where my **Angular array items are duplicated** when I refresh data (basically on **re-calling the method that creates the array**), as it adds the same items to the pre-existing array.

This happens when I switch between accounts, by selecting one of the drop down account IDs in my `<select>`.

**This is my HTML code from where I change the account/profile:**

```
<div ng-show="showSelectTwitterAccounts">
    <div>
        <div id="DropDownBox">
            <label for="ViewTwitterProfile">Select Twitter Profile: </label>
            <select ng-change="changeTwitterProfile()" ng-model="selectedTwitterProfileID" id="ViewTwitterProfile" ng-options="channelID for channelID in twitterChannels"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the method in my Controller that creates the array of profile IDs:**

```
function getChannelProfiles() {

    $scope.showSelectTwitterAccounts = true;

    GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID().then(function (brandProfileID) {

        SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles().then(function (channelProfiles) {

            channelProfiles.forEach(function (channel) {

                if (channel.brand_profile_id === brandProfileID && channel.channel_type === 'twitter') {

                    $scope.twitterChannels.push(channel.id);
                }
            });
            console.log($scope.twitterChannels);
        });
    });
}
```

**This is the method that gets called when I switch accounts:**

```
$scope.changeTwitterProfile = function () {

    $scope.dataModel = DataModelService.showDataLoadingAnimation();

    $scope.twitterPageMetrics = {};

    $scope.dataContent = false;

    $scope.showSelectTwitterAccounts = true;

    var twitterID = $scope.selectedTwitterProfileID;

    GetFusionDataService.getItems(getRequestURL(twitterID))

      .success(function (data) {
          handleDataRetrievalSuccess(data);
          getChannelProfiles();

      })

      .error(function (error, status) {
          handleDataRetrievalError(error, status);
      });

};
```

**I understand why the duplication is happening. The array is not cleared, and I keep pushing the same IDs into the array.**

I have tried a couple options to stop this, like adding

```
$scope.twitterChannels = [];
```

In the begging of my method that creates the view. This sets the array as an empty array as expected, and the array is recreated without duplicates.

**HOWEVER,** when I call my `$scope.changeTwitterProfile` method, everything works as planned, until it is time to create the array again. The array is cleared, and the data call is made to retrieve the data to filter for the array, but before the data is returned, the system steps into my `$scope.changeTwitterProfile` method, and by this time the array is still empty, and no profile is found. After this, the array gets created as it should.

Apologies for the long explanation - I just wanted to make it clear what i have tried and what happens.

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: "when I call my $scope.changeTwitterProfile method, everything works as planned, until it is time to create the array again. The array is cleared, and the data call is made to retrieve the data to filter for the array, but before the data is returned, the system steps into my $scope.changeTwitterProfile method, and by this time the array is still empty, and no profile is found. After this, the array gets created as it should." Can you elaborate on this a bit? What do you mean with "no profile is found"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding , 
You are clearing an array of ids which represents options of select box.

Here are the steps that you took

1. Clear an array  Made an $http call .
2. There are two $http service calls
3. fill the array with new elements

The reason you are seeing  no  drop-downs momentarily , is because angular runs digest cycle after $http promise are fulfilled. In your case , it runs  when  your first promise  GetUserAccessService.returnBrandProfileID() is fulfilled and your second promise  SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles() is yet to be fulfilled.

There are two ways you can tackle this.

1. Do not push identical elements in   $scope.twitterChannels.push(channel.id)
2. Clearing  $scope.twitterChannels when second promise 
   SocialMediaUserService.channelProfiles() is fulfilled [in its resolve function].

Comment: Thank you :). As I stepped out of the office yesterday. it literally hit me like a ton of bricks. The unresolved promise.... I am now simply clearing my array after the resolve. Works as expected.